# defined function repeatedly looping

Tags: python

Simple fix, but how can I make this stop looping? The output is it just asking for the values repeatedly. and also is there a way I can check all of the values to make sure there are in between 20 and 40?

```
def main():    
    print("Welcome to the autostacker")
    print(getDim())

def getDim():
    height = int(input("Enter the height: "))
    width = int(input("Enter the width: "))
    length = int(input("Enter the width: "))
    return getDim()


main()
```

Comment: Change `return getDim()` to `return height, weight, length`

Comment: How do you want to display the fields that are being input? What you have currently is a never ending recursive loop.

Comment: [20 < x < 40 for x in (height, width, length)]) == [True, True, True] would check for the input range for each value.

Comment: @ssm I believe it's width not weight :)

Comment: Ha ha thanks! I should be more careful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
def main():    
    print("Welcome to the autostacker")
    h, w, l = getDim()

    if 20 <= h <= 40:
        if 20 <= w <= 40:
            if 20 <= l <= 40:
                print "height is %d width is %d length is %d" % (h, w, l)
            else:
                print 'length out of range'
        else:
            print 'width out of range'
    else:
        print 'height out of range'




def getDim():
    height = int(input("Enter the height: "))
    width = int(input("Enter the width: "))
    length = int(input("Enter the length: "))
    return height, width, length

main()
```

Make sure you dont call getDim inside getDim unless you have some condition to eventually make it stop calling itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement in `getDim()` is the one to blame for looping I suppose. You can check if the values are in range as shown below.

```
def main():    
    print("Welcome to the autostacker")
    print(getDim())

def getDim():
    height = int(input("Enter the height: "))
    width = int(input("Enter the width: "))
    length = int(input("Enter the width: "))
    if 20 <= height <=40 and 20 <= width <= 40 and 20 <= length <= 40:
         print "all the values lie in the range"
         # DO WHAT YOU WANT
    else:
        print " values are not in range"
        # DO SOMETHING ELSE
    return height, width,length

main()
```